# User input in sublime text 2 extension

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2

I would like to pass user input to a Sublime Text 2 extension, which is written in python. One of the things I would like my plugin to do is to create new files, and I would like to pass the filename to the plugin, possibly without showing the whole console, but just a command-input line, similar to the line that show up when pressing [command + f]. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `show_input_panel` method described [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html).

Comment: How do you actually use that? As in what does the method belong to? `sublime.Window.show_input_panel();` doesn't work, nor do the variations of that I've tried

Comment: @WillshawMedia, If you just want to test it, you can run `sublime.Window.show_input_panel(sublime.active_window(), "Caption", "Initial text", None, None, None)` in the `Sublime Text`'s console. Other than that, if you tried to run __exactly__ the code you mentioned, it didn't work because you have to pass all the necessary arguments.

Comment: Thanks - I tried running it with some functions as arguments as well but I don't think I'd declared them properly. What you've said is great, cheers